# parseFloat causing weird calculations

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that needs to find the difference between 3 numbers. They can come in as strings, so I need to use `parseFloat` and maintain 2 decimal places. When I use parseFloat with negative numbers, I'm getting weird differences though.

```js
// This will output -0.004999999999636212
let temp = -8985.69 - -8985.915 - 0.23
console.log(temp);

// But this will output -4.365674488582272e-13
let x = -8985.69
let y = -8985.915
let z = 0.23
let temp2 = parseFloat(x.toFixed(2)) - parseFloat(y.toFixed(2)) - parseFloat(z.toFixed(2))
console.log(temp2);
```

I was looking at the [parseFloat docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and I see the part where the conversion may get changed when an invalid character is encountered. But I'm not seeing any wrong characters here and I'm not getting how the parsing stopping at any point would cause it to equal `-4.365674488582272e-13`

Comment: In general you should do all arithmetic with as many decimal places as you have. Only use `toFixed(2)` at the end when displaying the result.

Comment: Your example code would make a lot more sense if you actually had strings as you claim. If `y` was `"-8985.915"`, you would need the `parseFloat` first, eg `parseFloat(y).toFixed(2)`

Comment: @Phil great to know, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You second number has three decimal places and you set it `toFixed(2)` so it changes its value to `-8985.92`. When I use `.toFixed(3)` for it I get the first result you are looking for.

Comment: Ah I see, that's where the issue was. I also see the value in doing toFixed(2) at the end just for the result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

y = -8985.915

y.toFixed(2) => -8985.92

Answer (score 0):

You need to read David Goldberg's 1991 paper, [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About
Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Edavid/courses/cs552/S12/handouts/goldberg-floating-point.pdf)

And visit this web site: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic, or, Why don’t my numbers add up?](https://floating-point-gui.de/)